# Access VBA - method or data member not found error

Tags: database, vba, csv, ms-access, export-to-csv

I'm new to Access and thank you for reading this first.

I'm exporting a query in Access to a pipe delimited CSV file. The query is from a table which is ODBCed from SQL.

> I've been getting for the line `dbs.Recordset` : Method or data member not found error.

Huge thanks for any suggestion to fix this.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub Command12_Click()
Dim dbs As DAO.database 
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim intFile As Integer
Dim strFilePath As String
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim strHold

strFilePath = "C:\temp\TEST.csv"

Set dbs = CurrentDb

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("T_Export_CSV", dbOpenForwardOnly)

intFile = FreeFile


Open strFilePath For Output As #intFile

Do Until rst.EOF
   For intCount = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
   strHold = strHold & rst(intCount).Value & "|"
   Next
   If Right(strHold, 1) = "|" Then
      strHold = Left(strHold, Len(strHold) - 1)
   End If
   Print #intFile, strHold
   rst.MoveNext
   strHold = vbNullString
Loop

Close intFile
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing

MsgBox ("Export Completed Successfully")
End Sub
```

Thank you so so much for your time and please leave any comment below for any clarification if needed. I will try my best to be responsive!

Comment: *ODBCed from SQL*? SQL is a language. What specific RDMS are you referring to? SQL Server? Postgres? MySQL? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: DAO is the default API in the MS Access object library. Try removing `DAO.` in the dim lines: `Dim dbs As Database: `Dim rst As Recordset`

Comment: @Parfait It's SQL Server! Thanks for asking
I did try it and still gives me "User defined type not defined error", highlighting the line.

Comment: That's very odd! What is your environment? Which Windows OS? Office version? Do you have full MS Access license? Did you recently change installation?

Comment: I'm using my work machine in Access 2010 under Windows 7

Comment: And also I don't recall that I have changed installation.. @Parfait

Comment: Try creating a brand new database and import all objects. Do not adjust default references unless you really need a library like MSXML. Then compile VBA code (Debug / Compile in IDE). Possibly your project was corrupted somehow.

Comment: @Parfait Yes sir! Will let you know :) Thank you!

Comment: @Parfait Wow the error message is gone!!

Comment: @Parfait Would you be able to suggest me any idea regarding 'Method or data member not found error.'?? I'd very much appreciated If you could leave an answer below! :) Thank you so much!!

Comment: I do not understand. Has your issue been resolved and you need explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Office 15.0 object library is the one you need to include in the references for O365 objects or Office 2013 Access VBA

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't seem to find "Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library" on my Access 2010..

Comment: Ah, 15.0 is an Access 2013 object library so you won't have it in 2010. Should the D be capitalized in database? I don't have a copy to check it.

Comment: Sorry again I don't quite understand what the D you were referring to

Comment: This line -- capitalize like this; DAO.Database
Dim dbs As DAO.database